# How would I be able to import random mathematical/arithmetic symbols such as * or / - + etc

Tags: python

I have started to program a code where it ask you a random arithmetic question. I have managed to find a way of importing random numbers between 1 and 100 but need help with importing a random arithmetic symbol. Here is what I have so far:

```
from random import randrange 
random_number = randrange(1, 100)
```

Comment: That's not very far. :) I think you should go and learn a little more about the language before asking here.

Comment: Hint: `random.choice` and the `operator` module.

Answer (score 2):

Python has a operator module which contains methods like `operator.add(), operator.sub()`, etc. So the concept is, you store the desired operator methods in a list and then you can use `random.choice()` to select any operator method from the chosen list.

```
from operator import *

import random

rand_operator = random.choice([add, sub, mul, div])

print rand_operator(1, 2)
```